# what is Active Record model in Yii php framework?

Tags: activerecord, yii

I am reading a tutorial about Yii framework. It uses a term that I don't know its meaning. it is "**Active Record model**" . It uses in database section tutorial.

Would you give me more explanation about this term ?

Answer (score 4):

From the Yii's documentation:

Active Record (AR) is a popular `Object-Relational Mapping` (ORM) technique. Each **AR class** represents a database table (or view) whose attributes are represented as the AR class properties, and an AR instance represents a row in that table. Common CRUD operations are implemented as AR methods. As a result, we can access our data in a more object-oriented way.

For example, we can use the following code to insert a new row to the tbl_post table:

```
$post=new Post;
$post->title='sample post';
$post->content='post body content';
$post->save();
```

In the following we describe how to set up AR and use it to perform CRUD operations. We will show how to use AR to deal with database relationships in the next section. For simplicity, we use the following database table for our examples in this section. Note that if you are using MySQL database, you should replace AUTOINCREMENT with AUTO_INCREMENT in the following SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_post (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    title VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    content TEXT NOT NULL,
    create_time INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

There is more on [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar/).